# How to create pivot table based on binary and categorical columns in DataFrame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, aggregate-functions

I have DataFrame in Python Pandas like below:

Data type:

- ID - numeric
- U1, U2, U3 - numeric (binary 0/1)
- CP - string (range)

| ID | U1 | U2 | U3 | CP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 10-20 |
| 222 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 10-20 |
| 333 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 20-30 |
| 444 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 40-50 |
| 555 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 10-20 |

And I need to aggregate above DataFrame using pivot table to have something like below:

- COUNT_CP - How many ID have defined in index combination U and CP columns (for example combination U1 -'1' and CP_10_20 have 3 IDs)
- COUNT_U - How many ID have '1' in each 'U' column (for example 3 IDs have '1' in column 'U1')
- idx - indexes columns

  | idx | idx | COUNT_CP | COUNT_U |
  | --- | --- | --- | --- |
  | U1 | CP_10_20 | 3 | 3 |
  |  | CP_20_30 | 0 | 3 |
  |  | CP_30_40 | 0 | 3 |
  |  | CP_40_50 | 0 | 3 |
  | U2 | CP_10_20 | 2 | 3 |
  |  | CP_20_30 | 0 | 3 |
  |  | CP_30_40 | 0 | 3 |
  |  | CP_40_50 | 1 | 3 |
  | U3 | CP_10_20 | 1 | 2 |
  |  | CP_20_30 | 0 | 2 |
  |  | CP_30_40 | 0 | 2 |
  |  | CP_40_50 | 1 | 2 |

How can I do that in Python Pandas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this using `melt` and `groupby`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': {0: 111, 1: 222, 2: 333, 3: 444, 4: 555},
 'U1': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 1},
 'U2': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 0},
 'U3': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 0},
 'CP': {0: '10-20', 1: '10-20', 2: '20-30', 3: '40-50', 4: '10-20'}})

df = df.drop(columns='ID').melt(id_vars='CP', var_name='idx', value_name='COUNT_CP')
df = df.groupby(['idx','CP'])['COUNT_CP'].sum().reset_index()
df['COUNT_U'] = df.groupby('idx')['COUNT_CP'].transform(sum)
df['CP'] = df['CP'].apply(lambda x: 'CP_' + '_'.join(x.split('-')))

print(df)
```

Output

```
  idx        CP  COUNT_CP  COUNT_U
0  U1  CP_10_20         3        3
1  U1  CP_20_30         0        3
2  U1  CP_40_50         0        3
3  U2  CP_10_20         1        3
4  U2  CP_20_30         1        3
5  U2  CP_40_50         1        3
6  U3  CP_10_20         1        2
7  U3  CP_20_30         0        2
8  U3  CP_40_50         1        2
```